# Windows: File Object Id to File Name

Tags: windows, file, hook, objectid

I am developing the explorer hook for monitoring data to portable devices through MTP protocol.
I hooked Delete() function from interface IPortableDeviceContent. This function gives me the list of file object IDs which needs to be deleted. 
I want here to know what is the name of file for which delete request is sent.
If I can get file name from the received file object then it will resolve my issue.

Please let me know if anyone has any solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

`HookDelete()` is the function which hooked for `IPortableDeviceContent::Delete()`.
Below is the answer to the above question. Thought it does not give me full path, it gives a file name at least.

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE PortableDeviceInternalHook::HookDelete(
IPortableDeviceContent *pTHIS,
const DWORD dwOptions,
IPortableDevicePropVariantCollection *pObjectIDs,
IPortableDevicePropVariantCollection **ppResults)
{
    DWORD count;
    if(S_OK == pObjectIDs->GetCount(&count))
    {
        HRESULT result = S_FALSE;
        bool blockOperation;
        CComPtr<IPortableDeviceProperties> spProperties;
        result = pTHIS->Properties(&spProperties);

        if(S_OK == result)
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                HRESULT propertyValueResult;

                PROPVARIANT propertyValue = {0};
                propertyValueResult = pObjectIDs->GetAt(i, &propertyValue);

                CComPtr<IPortableDeviceValues> spDeviceValues;
                result = S_FALSE;

                if(S_OK == propertyValueResult)
                {
                    result = spProperties->GetValues(propertyValue.pwszVal, NULL, &spDeviceValues);
                    PropVariantClear(&propertyValue);
                }
                if(S_OK == result)
                {
                    HRESULT hResult;
                    LPWSTR pFileName = NULL;

                    hResult = spDeviceValues->GetStringValue(WPD_OBJECT_ORIGINAL_FILE_NAME, &pFileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return m_pFnTrueDelete(pTHIS, dwOptions, pObjectIDs, ppResults);
}
```